# How to test a function in Kotlin with Junit

Tags: kotlin, junit

I write a program in Kotlin. The program is working fine, but I only test the function with running the program. I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know, how to modiy the test. Thanks in advance!

```
class Dice {
var firstDice = 1
var secondDice = 1
var thirdDice = 3
var fourthDice = 2
var fifthDice = 2
val dices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

fun throwDices() {
    firstDice = Random.nextInt(1,7)
    dices.add(firstDice)
    println("Eldobtad a kockákat, az első kocka értéke: $firstDice")
    secondDice = Random.nextInt(1,7)
    dices.add(secondDice)
    println("A második kocka értéke: $secondDice")
    thirdDice = Random.nextInt(1,7)
    dices.add(thirdDice)
    println("A harmadik kocka értéke: $thirdDice")
    fourthDice = Random.nextInt(1,7)
    dices.add(fourthDice)
    println("A negyedik kocka értéke: $fourthDice")
    fifthDice = Random.nextInt(1,7)
    dices.add(fifthDice)
    println("Az ötödik kocka értéke: $fifthDice")
    dices.sort()
    println(dices)
}

fun winningCheck() :Int {
    if(dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[0] == dices[2] && dices[0] == dices[3] && dices[0] == dices[4] ) {
        return 15
    }
    else if(dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[0] == dices[2] && dices[0] == dices[3]) {
        return  9
    }
    else if (dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[0] == dices[2] && dices[3] == dices[4]) {
        return 5
    }
    else if(dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[0] == dices[2] || dices[1] == dices[2] && dices[1] == dices[3] ||
            dices[2] == dices[3] && dices[2] == dices[4]) {
        return 3
    }
    else if(dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[2] == dices[3] ||
            dices[1] == dices[2] && dices[3] == dices[4] ||
            dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[3] == dices[4]) {
        return  2
    }else if (dices[0] == dices[1] || dices[1] == dices[2] || dices[2] == dices[3] || dices[3] == dices[4]) {
        return 1
    }
    else
        return 0
}
```

}

This is the class, I want to test, and here is the testing code:

```
class DiceTest {

private val dice = Dice()
private val dices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

@Before
fun init() {
    dice.firstDice = 1
    dice.secondDice = 1
    dice.thirdDice= 1
    dice.fourthDice = 1
    dice.fifthDice = 1

    dices.add(dice.firstDice)
    dices.add(dice.secondDice)
    dices.add(dice.thirdDice)
    dices.add(dice.fourthDice)
    dices.add(dice.fifthDice)
}

@Test
fun checkingFiveOfAKind () {
    assertEquals(15,dice.winningCheck())
}
```

And here is the error code:

[image]

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but ‘dices’ is not an English word — ‘dice’ is already plural; the singular is ‘die’.  One die, two dice.

Comment: Yes I know, like mouse and mice.  But it's easier for my eyes to use dice and dices.

Comment: (If it were me, I think I'd prefer ‘die’ and ‘dies’!  Regular, _and_ closer to the standard terms.)

Comment: Die and dies reminds me when someone die. The hungarian language also has words which have more meanings. And excuse me if my english isn't perfect. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example could be simplified to ask, why does't this code work:

```
@Test
fun checkingFiveOfAKind() {
    val dices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    
    val anotherDices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

    val result :Int
    if(anotherDices[0] == anotherDices[1] 
       && anotherDices[0] == anotherDices[2] 
       && anotherDices[0] == anotherDices[3] 
       && anotherDices[0] == anotherDices[4] ) {
       result = 15
    } else {
       result = 0
    }
 
    assertEquals(15, result)
}
```

But this code does work:

```
@Test
fun checkingFiveOfAKind() {
    val dices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    dices.add(1)
    
    val result :Int
    if(dices[0] == dices[1] 
       && dices[0] == dices[2] 
       && dices[0] == dices[3] 
       && dices[0] == dices[4] ) {
       result = 15
    } else {
       result = 0
    }
 
    assertEquals(15, result)
}
```

---

Or written another way:

You are adding your dice rolls to a variable called `dices` but this is a declared in your test, it is not the variable you are using inside your `Dice` class, that is another List.

You may be able to fix your test like this:

```
class DiceTest {

private val dice = Dice()

@Before
fun init() {
    dice.firstDice = 1
    dice.secondDice = 1
    dice.thirdDice= 1
    dice.fourthDice = 1
    dice.fifthDice = 1

    dice.dices.add(dice.firstDice)
    dice.dices.add(dice.secondDice)
    dice.dices.add(dice.thirdDice)
    dice.dices.add(dice.fourthDice)
    dice.dices.add(dice.fifthDice)
}

@Test
fun checkingFiveOfAKind () {
    assertEquals(15, dice.winningCheck())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is:

instead of adding dices like this:

```
dices.add(dice.firstDice)
```

you need to add like this:

```
dice.dices.add(dice.firstDice)
```

As `winningCheck()` is checking inside the `Dice` class

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime well done for reading my answer and handing him the fish -.-

Answer (score 1):

As a coding best practice side note:

Another way to test your dice class, would be to override the part you are trying to control (the random number generator). That way you can test the public interface of your class, instead of exposing the fields for testing. Something like this:

```
interface NumberGenerator {
     fun generate() : Int
}

class RandomNumberGenerator : NumberGenerator {
    override fun generate() {
        return Random.nextInt(1,7)
    }
}

class Dice(private val numberGenerator: NumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator()) {
    
    private var firstDice = 1
    private var secondDice = 1
    private var thirdDice = 3
    private var fourthDice = 2
    private var fifthDice = 2
    private val dices: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
    
    fun throwDices() {
        firstDice = numberGenerator.generate()
        dices.add(firstDice)
        println("Eldobtad a kockákat, az első kocka értéke: $firstDice")
        secondDice = numberGenerator.generate()
        dices.add(secondDice)
        println("A második kocka értéke: $secondDice")
        thirdDice = numberGenerator.generate()
        dices.add(thirdDice)
        println("A harmadik kocka értéke: $thirdDice")
        fourthDice = numberGenerator.generate()
        dices.add(fourthDice)
        println("A negyedik kocka értéke: $fourthDice")
        fifthDice = numberGenerator.generate()
        dices.add(fifthDice)
        println("Az ötödik kocka értéke: $fifthDice")
        dices.sort()
        println(dices)
    }
    
    fun winningCheck() :Int {
        // Your winning check code here
    }
}
```

Then in your tests:

```
class TestNumberGenerator(
    private val numbersToReturn: List<Int>,
) : NumberGenerator {
    private var count = 0

    override fun generate() {
        return numbersToReturn.get(count).also {
            if(count == numbersToReturn.size) count = 0 else count++
        }
    }
}


class DiceTest {
    
    @Test
    fun checkingFiveOfAKind () {
        val dice = Dice(TestNumberGenerator(listOf(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)))

        dice.throwDices()

        assertEquals(15, dice.winningCheck())
    }

}
```

The `TestNumberGenerator` still assumes that all dice are rolled in order and only once each, but it'll work with your current code, and it makes your test much more understandable :-).

Comment: I'm new in Kotlin. Before Kotlin I learned Java, but I think Kotlin is my language to learn. I tried to check winning with comparing the dices, but I think it's easier to check when it's sorted in a list. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!